# How to sort custom field date in Wordpress outside loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to sort pages by a custom field which has the 'yyyy/mm/dd' format. The problem I have is no matter what I have tried I keep getting the list back in alphabetical order by title.

Is there anyway to do a query outside the loop and have the pages returned in the sorted order?

```
$args = array(
    'parent' => 462, 
    'child_of' => 462,
    'sort_column' => 'Date',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'sort_order' => 'ASC'
); 
$pageposts = get_pages($args);
```

I did try with this as well, but I still cannot seem to get it to work.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'Date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'parent' => 462, 
    'child_of' => 462,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'ASC'
); 
$pageposts = get_pages($args);
```

I did try with meta_value as well as meta_value_num. I am completely lost and am not really understanding why I cannot figure this out. Thank you all in advance for any help. I know this may be remedial to most, so I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your custom query because `wordpress` `get_pages,get_posts` will sort the `meta_value` as string so if you use the above functions your field will be treated as the string not the `date` here is the example you can add further your conditions in the query

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "
        SELECT wp.*
        FROM $wpdb->posts wp, $wpdb->postmeta wm
        WHERE wp.ID = wm.post_id
        AND wm.meta_key = 'Date'
        AND wp.post_status = 'publish'
        AND wp.post_type = 'page'
        AND wp.post_parent = '462'
        ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(wm.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') ASC
        ";

    $pages = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);
```

Note**The date must be inputted in the American format i.e 21/02/2009 for it to work**

Hope it makes sense

Comment: Actually that was wonderful!! I understand perfectly. I am sorry I was under the impression I could not do the "SELECT" type of query through a function outside the loop. But your post made perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use 'sort_column' => 'post_date',

Comment: I am sorry maybe I was not clear. The date I need to sort by is not the post date, but a custom field which happens to be a date.